# How can I increase the font with which text is displayed in BlueSky Statistics?

Tags: r, font-size

Teaching in class and showing the students the syntax but the font is too small for the students to see

Answer (score 0):

You can control the font size by holding the CTRL key down and rolling your mouse scroll wheel.